# if-else statement on change of a select box

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get it to select the variable "choice" to decide which element is selected in the drop down. The problem is when I click "slogan" and then go back to "header" it starts writing into both text fields.

**HTML**

```
<select class="choice">
    <option value="h">Header</option>
    <option value="s">Slogan</option>
</select>   
<input class="selecttext" type="text" placeholder="Main Text"></input>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".fontsdiv .choice").on("change", function() {
    var choice = $(".choice").val();
    if (choice === "h") {
        $(".selecttext").keyup(function(event) {
            var titlechange = $(".selecttext").val();
            $(".maintitle").html("<h1 class='maintitle'>" + titlechange + "</h1>");
            $(".maintitle").draggable();

        });
    } else if (choice === "s") {
        $(".selecttext").keyup(function(event) {
            var titlechanges = $(".selecttext").val();
            $(".secondtitle").html("<h1 class='secondtitle'>" + titlechanges + "</h1>");
            $(".secondtitle").draggable();

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: that is because you are using `onchange`.. that is what it is supposed to do when the value is *changed*.. maybe put another conditional statement in there to counteract if the `choice !== "h"`?

Comment: what do you want to do, please clear in question?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are binding event handler in the `change` event a *new* event handler is attached to `input` element every time you change the value, in short multiple event handler are getting attached.

You need to check the value in the `keyup` event of `input` element.

```js
$(".selecttext").keyup(function(event) {
  var choice = $(".choice").val();
  var titlechange = $(".selecttext").val();

  if (choice === "h") {
    $(".maintitle").html("<h1 class='maintitle'>" + titlechange + "</h1>");
    //$(".maintitle").draggable();
  } else if (choice === "s") {
    $(".secondtitle").html("<h1 class='secondtitle'>" + titlechanges + "</h1>");
    //$(".secondtitle").draggable();
  }

});
$(".choice").on("change", function() {
  //Clear value
  $(".selecttext").val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="choice">
  <option value="h">Header</option>
  <option value="s">Slogan</option>
</select>
<input class="selecttext" type="text" placeholder="Main Text" />
<br/>
<div class='maintitle'></div>
<div class='secondtitle'></div>
```